# User profile wont show and cannot be updated : Firebase and VueJS

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an app and in this app I have a profile page. In this profile page I want to show the information about the current user, such as name, username, ... I've created a `firestore()` function which get the collection of the user, via the user uid (because my user collection as the same name as the user uid). When I launch my app, nothing appears and when I want to update the name or username, by enter some text in the inputs, I have an error. This error tells me that :

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined"

found in

---> <Profile> at popup/components/profile/extension_userAccount.vue
       <ExtensionMainComponent> at popup/components/extension_mainComponent.vue
         <App> at popup/App.vue
           <Root>

TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined
    at VueComponent.updateProfile (extension_userAccount.vue?../node_modules/babel-loader/lib!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options:258)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js:1853)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js:2178)
    at HTMLButtonElement.original._wrapper (vue.runtime.esm.js:6901)
```

But when I `console.log` the profile array, I have all my information shown.

There is my `account.vue` page :

```
<div>
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <input type="text" v-model="profile.name">
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Username</h3>
  <input type="text" v-model="profile.username">
</div>
<button @click="updateProfile">Modify</button>


<script>

import {fb,db} from '../../firebase/init'

export default {
    name: "profile",
    data() {
        return {
            profile: {
                name: null,
                username: null
            }
        }
    },

    firestore(){
        const user = fb.auth().currentUser;
        return {
            profile: db.collection('users').doc(user.uid),
        }
    },

    methods:
        updateProfile() {
            this.$firestore.profile.update(this.profile);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And there is my `firebaseInit.js` :

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firebase-auth";
import "firebase/firebase-firestore";

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};


const fb = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();

export {fb,db}
```

If someone could help me ;)